# Tkinter Text Widget Font Bug

Tags: python, json, tkinter, tkinter-text

Run the code for it to make sense,
go to Appearance >> Font >> Size,
No matter what, the font size turns to 48 and config.json has font size also equal to 48.

I tried logging Root.Size >> s in the function and and print the sizes while generating them in the for loop, here was the result:
(generation)
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
22
24
26
28
30
32
34
36
38
40
42
44
46
48
(function call)
(all cases)
48
(config.json)
{"wordwrap": "char", "font": ["Helvetica", 48]}

code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog  # , colorchooser, constants, ttk
# from typing import Literal, List
# import pickle as p
# import time as t
# import random as r
import json as js
# import math as m
# import sys, os
import tkinter.font


class Root:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title('Deltae Text Editor')
        self.root.iconbitmap('DeltaeTextEditorLogo.ico')

        self.fonts = []
        for name in sorted(tkinter.font.families()):
            if name[0] != '@':
                self.fonts.append(name)

        self.text = Frame()
        self.text.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)

        yScroll = Scrollbar(master=self.text, orient=VERTICAL)
        yScroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        xScroll = Scrollbar(master=self.text, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        xScroll.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

        with open("config.json") as con:
            self.config = js.load(con)

        self.textbox = Text(master=self.text, font=self.config['font'], yscrollcommand=yScroll.set,
                            xscrollcommand=xScroll.set, wrap=self.config['wordwrap'], undo=TRUE)
        self.textbox.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)

        yScroll.config(command=self.textbox.yview)
        xScroll.config(command=self.textbox.xview)

        self.menu = Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=self.menu)

        file_menu = Menu(self.menu, tearoff=False)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file_menu)
        file_menu.add_command(label='Open', command=self.open)
        file_menu.add_command(label='Save', command=self.save)
        file_menu.add_command(label='Save as', command=self.save_as)
        file_menu.add_command(label='New', command=self.new)
        file_menu.add_separator()
        file_menu.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.root.quit)

        edit_menu = Menu(self.menu, tearoff=False)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label='Edit', menu=edit_menu)
        edit_menu.add_command(label='Cut', command=self.cut)
        edit_menu.add_command(label='Copy', command=self.copy)
        edit_menu.add_command(label='Paste', command=self.paste)
        edit_menu.add_separator()
        edit_menu.add_command(label='Undo', command=self.undo)
        edit_menu.add_command(label='Redo', command=self.redo)

        edit_menu = Menu(self.menu, tearoff=False)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label='Appearance', menu=edit_menu)

        Word = Menu(edit_menu, tearoff=False)
        edit_menu.add_cascade(label='Wordwrap', menu=Word)

        Word.add_radiobutton(label='None', command=self.none)
        Word.add_radiobutton(label='Character', command=self.char)
        Word.add_radiobutton(label='Word', command=self.word)

        FontM = Menu(edit_menu, tearoff=False)
        edit_menu.add_cascade(label='Font', menu=FontM)

        SizeM = Menu(FontM, tearoff=False)
        FontM.add_cascade(label='Size', menu=SizeM)

        for size in range(8, 50, 2):
            SizeM.add_radiobutton(label=str(size), command=lambda: self.Size(size))

        FamilyM = Menu(FontM, tearoff=False)
        FontM.add_cascade(label='Font Family', menu=FamilyM)

        for font in self.fonts:
            FamilyM.add_radiobutton(label=font, command=str(self.Family(font)))

        self.file: str = ''

        self.root.mainloop()
        self.text = None

    def open(self):
        self.textbox.delete('1.0', END)
        self.file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/', title='Open File', filetypes=(('Text Files', '*.txt'),
                                                                                             ('All Files', '*.*')))
        try:
            if self.file:
                self.text = open(self.file, 'r')
                self.textbox.insert(END, self.text.read())
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            if self.file:
                text = open(self.file, 'rb')
                self.textbox.insert(END, str(text.read()))
        finally:
            self.text.close()

    def save(self):
        if self.file:
            self.file = open(self.file, 'w')
            self.file.write(self.textbox.get('1.0', END))
            self.file.close()
        else:
            self.save_as()

    def save_as(self):
        self.file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir='/', defaultextension='.*', title='save as', filetypes=((
                'Text Files', '*.txt'), ('All Files', '*.*')))
        if self.file:
            try:
                self.file = open(self.file, 'w')
                self.file.write(self.textbox.get('1.0', END))
                self.file.close()
            except UnicodeEncodeError:
                self.file = open(self.file, 'wb')
                self.file.write(bytes(self.textbox.get('1.0', END)))
                self.file.close()

    def new(self):
        self.file = ''
        self.textbox.delete('1.0', END)

    def cut(self):
        pass

    def copy(self):
        pass

    def paste(self):
        pass

    def undo(self):
        pass

    def redo(self):
        pass

    def none(self):
        self.textbox.config(wrap=NONE)
        with open('config.json', 'w') as con:
            self.config['wordwrap'] = 'none'
            js.dump(self.config, con)

    def char(self):
        self.textbox.config(wrap=CHAR)
        with open('config.json', 'w') as con:
            self.config['wordwrap'] = 'char'
            js.dump(self.config, con)

    def word(self):
        self.textbox.config(wrap=WORD)
        with open('config.json', 'w') as con:
            self.config['wordwrap'] = 'word'
            js.dump(self.config, con)

    def Size(self, s: int):
        # def Size(self, s: str):
        #        rewrite config to include s
        #        configure textbox s
        #        rewrite config json to include s
        self.config['font'][1] = s
        self.textbox.config(font=self.config['font'])
        with open('config.json', 'w') as con:
            js.dump(self.config, con)

    def Family(self, f: str):
        # def Size(self, f: str):
        #        rewrite config to include s
        #        configure textbox s
        #        rewrite config json to include s
        pass


def main():
    root = Root()
    root.copyright = None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Change `command=lambda: self.Size(size)` to `command=lambda size=size: self.Size(size)`.

Comment: There's a lot of code that is unrelated to the question being asked. Can you please try to reduce the code down to only the code necessary to reproduce the problem? See [mcve].

Comment: I can't get file  config.json.